# Route of type POST is not working on server in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a route of type post in a server but it gave me a `500 error` when I do the call from `POSTMAN`

With routes of type get, I don't get any errors this only happens on POST

This is the error I'm getting in POSTMAN: https://www.screencast.com/t/zN6XqQxQ

This is my route

```php
Route::post('/integrations', 'IntegrationsController@store');
```

This is my controller

```php
class IntegrationsController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return "this route works";
    }

}
```

Comment: what Laravel version are you using? and did this work to your Laravel application, did you use the API route?

Comment: Laravel 6, well this route it's supposed to act like an API route with the difference that is on `web.php` @codeformoney

Comment: So, if you change this specific route to a get it works as expected?

Comment: @RyanH It should work as it is right now, inside the `web.php` are other routes of type post that works but mine is not working

Comment: What do those working routes return?  I am still convinced you can not just return a string.  Laravel utilizes middleware and a request/response structure.

Comment: can you identify what are the errors thrown in your request?

Comment: @codeformoneyThis is what I get in `POSTMAN` https://www.screencast.com/t/F522lzSxbo

Comment: @RyanH yeah I tried to return anything type of response also and it gave me always the same error, I have tried this `return response()->json([
            'success' => [
                'message' => 'New records inserted in the database'
            ]
        ], 201);`

Comment: The error is going to be in the body of that HTML response you're getting. Your screenshot does not show what it is. You'll need to look at that HTML response to see what the error is.

Comment: You can render the html in Postman to view the error by changing the display to “Preview”. Click where it says “Pretty” and change it to “Preview”, then screenshot that page with the error.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in **text form** - there's no need to add a text answer here using an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you send a post request with data without csrf token

That what I think the issue is

So, if that for test purposes you can temporary disable it by going to

\app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

add your route to this protected variable

```
 protected $except = [
        '/integrations'
    ];
```

and it will work

side note: if this endpoint is gonna be consumed only by a mobile
it's not recommended to put it in the web.php route file

instead, you can add it to api.php which will automatically remove the csrf protection because you basically don't need it

Hope that helps

Comment: Invalid CSRF would return a 419, not a 500.

Comment: This was actually the problem, once I added my route to the array started to work